# Who will the tag creation be attributed to if I edit a post to add a new tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, questions

I have seen a few questions created by some new users which are missing a very obvious tag, for the simple reason that this tag doesn't exist yet and they probably didn't have the privilege yet.

My question is, if I go ahead and edit these posts to include the missing tag, who will the tag creation be attributed to, me or the original poster? Needless to say, I'll update either way, but I'm just curious how this translates behind the hood.

By "attributed" I mean that it would count towards the Taxonomist badge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be attributed to the creator of the tag. That is, you in this case. The OP did not create that tag. You did.